# How to find duplicated title values in a map

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript, come from Java, this is less intuitive for me.

I would like to check for duplication of the title value and concatenate to the duplicated title the producer name

My idea is to sort the values and then check each one with is next for duplication

Can you suggest me how to implement this kind of solution?

```
 function getItems(itemKeys, itemSortOrders, itemsMap) 
 {
        var items = _.map(itemKeys, function(itemKey, index) {
            var item = itemsMap[itemKey];
            return _.extend({
                key: itemKey,
                title: item.title,
                imageURL: item.imageURL,
                formattedPrice: utils.formatMoney(item.price),
                producerKey: item.producerKey,
                producerTitle: item.producerTitle,
                allowOrder: true,
                sortOrder: itemSortOrders[index]
            }, calculateItemDetails(item.deliveryDayAvailable, item.deliveryDayStatus, item.deliveryDayUsageCount));
        });
        items = _.compact(items);
        return items;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO this is what i did eventually and this worked

```
        var duplicateMap = {};
        _.each(itemsMap, function(item) {
            var title = item.title.trim();
            if (duplicateMap[title]) {
                duplicateMap[title] = 2;
            }
            else {
                duplicateMap[title] = 1;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test if item have duplicates with this function, it use filter to find the same items and check if the length is larger then 1.

```js
function haveDuplicates(itemKeys, itemsMap, itemKey) {
    var item = itemsMap[itemKey];
    var dups = itemKeys.filter(function(key) {
        return itemsMap[key] == item;
    });
    return dups.length > 1;
}
var itemsMap = {
  'foo': 'Lorem',
  'bar': 'Lorem',
  'baz': 'Ipsum',
  'quux': 'Dolor'
};
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var itemKeys = Object.keys(itemsMap);
itemKeys.map(function(key) {
  output.innerHTML += itemsMap[key] + ' ' + 
    (haveDuplicates(itemKeys, itemsMap, key) ? 'have' : 'don\'t have') + '\n';
});
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: i added this code as part of your help
is this the correct way?
cause it didnt work for me

  var item = itemsMap[itemKey];

                var dups= itemKeys.filter(function(key) {
                    return itemsMap[key].title == item.title;
                });
                    var title = item.title;
                if(dups.length > 1) {
                    title = title + " (" + item.producerTitle +" )";
                }
                return _.extend({
                    key: itemKey,
                    title: title,

Comment: @asfmlr don't know what's wrong with your code, it should work. Are you sure the title is duplicated maybe the text look the same but have different case.

Comment: Thanks, 
I tried to to the simplest way, but still doesn't work
Creating a map and check if the title exists
            for(var key in itemKeys ) {
                var item = itemsMap[key];
                if(!duplicateMap.contains(item.title)) {
                    duplicateMap[item.title] = 1;
                }
                else {
                    duplicateMap[item.title] = 2;
                }
            };

But I'm getting undefined for the title

Comment: @asfmlr You need to use `duplicateMap[itemKeys].title = ...` or `item.title = ...`